# Including a vector of Objects within an Object, using reference

Tags: c++

I am trying to establish the relationship between two different classes with my code. I have a class Object and a Class Interface. The Object class can hold any number of Interfaces, of which I have chosen to store within a vector of unique pointers.

My Object class definition is:

```
#ifndef BASE_OBJECT
#define BASE_OBJECT

#include <vector>
#include <memory>

#include "./Interface.hxx"

class Object
{
/*****************
    Properties
******************/
//General
std::string ObjectType;

//Interfaces - All objects have at least one sender or receiver
//(otherwise it does nothing)
//Senders
typedef std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Interface>> Senders;

//Receivers
typedef std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Interface>> Receivers;

/**********************
    Member functions
**********************/
public:
    //Standard constructor
    Object(void);

    //Copy constructor
    Object(const Object& from);

    //Virtual destructor
    virtual ~Object(void);

    //Add an interface
    void add_interface(std::string type);
};

#endif
```

I haven't included my interface class, as it doesn't define anything as yet. When trying to add an interface to my Object, I call the following routine from my main function:

```
//Add interface to object
MyObject->add_interface("Sender");
```

Which calls the routine add_interface:

```
//Add an interface to the object
void Object::add_interface(std::string type)
{
if (type.compare("Sender")){
    auto intf = std::unique_ptr<Interface>(new Interface);
    this->Senders.push_back(std::move(intf));
}
else if (type.compare("Receiver")){
    auto intf = std::unique_ptr<Interface>(new Interface);
    this->Receivers.push_back(std::move(intf));
}
else{
    //Throw exception
}
}
```

Currently within visual studio express, the "Senders" and "Receivers" is highlighted with the warning "Error: type name is not allowed", and upon compilation I get the following error:

'function-style cast': illegal as right side of -> operator.

I am new to smart pointers and OOP, so I am not really sure what I am doing wrong here. Can anyone please explain my mistake? Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have:

```
typedef std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Interface>> Senders;
typedef std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Interface>> Receivers;
```

`Senders` and `Receivers` are types, indeed. They are not objects. Hence,
`this->Senders` and `this->Receivers` does not make sense.

You need to use:

```
Senders senders;     // A variable that can hold senders
Receivers receivers; // A variable that can hold receivers.
```

And then use:

```
this->senders.push_back(std::move(intf));
```

and

```
this->receivers.push_back(std::move(intf));
```

Comment: Great, thanks! Is there any benefit to defining the type within the object?

Comment: You will not pollute outer scope with inner types

Comment: It adds an extra bit of readability. You can easily get away with define one `typedef` though -- `Interfaces` and use `Interfaces senders; Interfaces receivers;`.

Answer (score 0):

Senders and Receivers in your code are just types, not fields. You should declare two fields, e.g.: Senders senders; Receiers receivers

Answer (score 0):

`Senders` and `Receivers` are `typedef`s within your `Object` class, not members.

Objects (or variables) and types cannot generally have the same name, in the same scope